# RxSwift Realm observe Array in RunLoop

Tags: ios, swift, realm, grand-central-dispatch, rx-swift

I am using RxSwift and RxRealm and want to be able to observe changes of resources based on a predicate. The function would be like this

```
func observe(type: String) -> Observable<[MyRealmObject]> {
  let realm = configureRealm() // 1
  let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "type = %@", type)
  let resources = realm
    .objects(MyRealmObject.self)
    .filter(predicate)
  return Observable.array(from: resources) // 2
}
```

However, Realm requires `// 2` to be run on a thread with a run loop AND `// 1` and `// 2` have to be called on the same thread.

I can't guarantee that the observe(type: String) function is already being called on a thread with run loop, so I probably have to switch to one within the function - but that way i wont be able to have a synchronous return value anymore.

**Any ideas on how to make sure realm observations are always guaranteed to be on a specific run loop?**

## Update: Using custom Thread with run-loop - but I'm still not satisfied

I created a custom thread that has a run loop but getting the synchronous return value is just ugly - as you can see i used a DispatchGroup to synchronize and i'd really like to avoid that.

```
func observe(type: String) -> Observable<[MyRealmObject]> {
  let observableCalculation = {
    let realm = configureRealm() // 1
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "type = %@", type)
    let resources = realm
      .objects(MyRealmObject.self)
      .filter(predicate)
    return Observable.array(from: resources) // 2
  }

  if Thread.current == self.realmObservationThread {
    return observableCalculation()
  }

  var o: Observable<[MyRealmObject]>!
  let g = DispatchGroup()
  g.enter()
  self.realmObservationThread.runloop?.perform {
    o = observableCalculation()
    g.leave()
  }
  g.wait()
  return o
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Do you really have to observe each and every array individually by creating the observable. I think it is better to observe `Results` which is the result of query instead of Observing each items like so.

See sample from [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Results.html#/s:10RealmSwift7ResultsC7observeySo20RLMNotificationTokenCyAA0A16CollectionChangeOyACyxGGcF).

You could then wrap this inside your own observable and based on the changes in the Result, you could then do a callback for specific object.

Comment: Interesting approach, I'll try that out.